# Discord.js leaves me with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" while trying to convert in game messages to discord messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, minecraft

I recently tried running a project from github (https://github.com/mew/discord-hypixel-bridge) that is using node.js and is supposed to link a discord server channel to a guild channel on the minecraft server I am trying to use this for. What it is basically supposed to be doing is detecting when a message is sent in the discord channel, send it in the guild chat with the bot account I linked and receive messages people in the guild chat type and send them to the discord server using my bot in it.
Sending the message from the discord to the guild chat has no problem, however when anyone types anything in the guild chat while trying to send that info to my discord server it crashes and leaves me with a few errors in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\index.js:52
            if (v[2].includes(name + ":") || v[3].includes(name + ":")) return;
                     ^
    
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at Bot.<anonymous> (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\index.js:52:18)
    at Bot.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\node_modules\mineflayer\lib\plugins\chat.js:79:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at FullPacketParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\node_modules\minecraft-protocol\src\client.js:89:12)
    at FullPacketParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:298:12)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:280:11)
    at FullPacketParser.Readable.push (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:241:10)
    at FullPacketParser.Transform.push (C:\Users\betab\Pictures\Epicness\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:139:32)
```

I don't really have an idea why this happens as I am not the one that coded this so help is appreciated!
As I am not sure why this happens but I have included the [index.js](https://discord.com/channels/742811294578638970/742814559433261118/791424502965207061) file and an example of the [config.json](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/742814559433261118/791439562156933130/config.json) file! I don't have any idea on what is going here and I don't have much knowledge and just wanted to able to run this!
Thank you! <3

Comment: Of undefined means the element of which you are trying to perform the method on is undefined; `v[2]` in this case, is returning undefined.

Comment: Need to know where and what the 'v' array is being assigned, and if it is being assigned before this function is befing run. BTW what is it returning? Nothing?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really have any idea what is happening and just wanted to run this with my almost non existent knowledge, but I guess it is too complicated for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the [project you are using](https://github.com/mew/discord-hypixel-bridge) is a work in progress (according to its README on github) and is therefore not guaranteed to work. It wouldn't be a good idea to try and use it especially if you have limited javascript or discord.js knowledge, given that it could contain numerous errors and potentially may not work at all.

**The Problem**

As for the error you are getting, allow me to explain it. Here's the lines of code in which the error occurs:

```
let v = msg.split(" ", 2);
if (v[2].includes(name + ":") || v[3].includes(name + ":")) return;
```

`msg.split(" ")` splits up a string based on spaces, and creates an array of each item between the spaces (the words of a sentence). So essentially, if you were to `split()` the sentence `"Hello my friend"`, you would get the array result: `["Hello", "my", "friend"]`.

However, the code you are using does `msg.split(" ", 2)`. The second argument (the number) in this code indicates how many times to split the string. Because the number specified is 2, it will only split the string twice. This may lead to a common misconception, which the author of the project you are using also fell victim to.

So here's what doing `.split(" ", 2)` would do to the example sentence `"Hello my friend"` from before: `["Hello", "my"]`. I'm guessing the project's author actually wanted the code to do something like `["Hello", "my friend"]`, but they didn't realize that `.split()` doesn't work like that, hence falling victim to the common misconception.

So why does this cause an error? Because the `if` statement tries to use `.includes()` on `v[2]`, where `v` is the array result of the split. So let's say `v` is the accurate result of our example from above (`["Hello", "my"]`). Arrays have indexes that you use to access the data inside them, and the indexes begin at zero. So in our example, `v[0]` is "Hello" and `v[1]` is "my". But the project's code is trying to get `v[2]`, which would be the third element in the array. However, as aforementioned, the array output of `.split(" ", 2)` will only have two elements in them; there is no third element in `v`. Therefore, `v[2]` is `undefined`, and that's why the error occurs.

**The Solution**

Assuming I understood the author's intentions correctly, here's one way that you could fix this particular error:

```
let v = [msg.split(" ")[0], msg.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")];
if (v.length < 2 || v[1].includes(name + ":")) return;
```

Instead of doing the erroneous split from before, now we're doing something different. We're creating our own array. For the first element: we insert the first element of the actual split of the message. For the second element: we take the split of the message, get every element except the first one (using `.slice(1)`, which "slices" the array starting with index 1 and ending at the end), and unsplit/join these elements of the original split using a space; essentially, we get everything in the message after the first space. This allows us to check for `name + ":"` in all parts of the message following the first part, to make sure that the name is in the right part of the message.

Now there are other ways of doing this, such as using `.replace()` to replace the first space in `msg` with some sequence of characters, and then splitting the output of that by those sequence of characters. This is just one way to do it.

I also changed the `if` statement to make sure that the array actually has at least two elements in it. That's because the array will only have less than two elements (one or less) if the message was empty or if a message wasn't sent at all, and you wouldn't want the code to execute in either of those cases. As to why you wouldn't want to do so: if a user sends an empty message in mc, do you really want to send the empty message in discord? It's not even possible to do so regardless, it would cause an error in discord.js.

**Notes**

Though these fixes should solve the problem you were experiencing, I doubt this will get this project working. I have tested neither the project nor my fixed version, but I'm pretty sure it will have more errors, as the code seems pretty incomplete. And given that the author fell victim to the aforementioned common misconception, they may have made more simple logical errors in the code that will prevent it from functioning properly.

Also, for future reference when asking questions on StackOverflow, please provide the relevant code directly in your question via code blocks like the ones in this answer. Your question only contains a single line of code, and does not contain all of the relevant parts of the code (you should have included some of the lines above and below the line you provided). You *should not* solely attach a link to an external source such as Github when asking a question here, and it is also a major inconvenience for answerers.